# How Can I add more then one query in one connection (Visual Studio C# to PostgreSQL)

Tags: c#, postgresql, connection

I add data to database

```
NpgsqlConnection conn1 = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=test;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;");
conn.Open();

NpgsqlCommand comm = new NpgsqlCommand();
comm.Connection = conn;
comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test";
NpgsqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
    dt.Load(dr);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

comm.Dispose();
conn.Close();
```

so far everything is fine
but I want to add more then one query in one connection
e.g.

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test";
NpgsqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

// some code for view data in dataGridView1

comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM test1";
NpgsqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

// and some code for view data in dataGridView2
```

but I can't

or maybe use transaction but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: And you're getting what.. Something like "there is already an open reader associated with this connection" ? Closing a connection doesn't actually close a connection, it just returns it to a pool of connections from which it was borrowed by Open; feel free to open and close them all the time, once per query (unless you need a transaction which this doesn't appear to) and it'll be fine. There are easier ways of working with data than what you're doing here, by the way

Answer (score 0):

Easier life when you use a dataadapter:

```
var conn = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=test;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;"

var da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM one", conn);
var dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
grid1.DataSource = dt;

da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM two", conn);
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
grid2.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: when i use this code

my dataGridView is empty. My "Program" should work like this. There are 3 textBox-es, 1 button and 1 dataGridView I fill textBox-es and click the button. then I add this data to the test table and refresh the dataGridView with the data from the test table

Comment: *when i use this code my dataGridView is empty* - how would you like me to debug this from the information you've given? It's absolutely certain that you've had to translate the code from what I wrote here to what you've put in your program, so you're going to need to give more information.. Use the debugger to step it and see at what point things go wrong: do you get data in your datatable? Do you link it to the correct grid? Do you catch any exceptions and throw them away?